# Computer doesn't power on yet PSU is fine

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have an old computer with an Asus P4T-E motherboard. The power switch has been a problem in the past, so I added a new momentary switch to the case and connected it to the motherboard's ATX Power Switch header pins.

The computer has been working fine ever since, yet when I tried to start it a few days ago, it would no longer start after being powered off for a few months.

I've checked the switch with a multimeter, no problem there. I checked the PSU and all voltages checked out fine. The on-board LED of the motherboard is active, so the motherboard has power.

Yes, the computer is old, and yes it has already been replaced, but I still have some uses for it so I'd like to get it up and running again.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what I should check next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the capacitors for leaks and bulges.  Since its really old, your capacitors could be failing.

Comment: @essjae: Thanks, but sorry, forgot to mention... The PSU is fairly new, so no capacitor issues there, and I've checked the motherboard for failing capacitors, but they all are in mint condition. I still have a 486 and several old Pentiums that don't have any capacitor issues, so I'd expect the same of a Pentium IV motherboard to be honest.